# Define timedelta in Python based on two strings

Tags: python-3.x, variables, timedelta

I have this two strings:

```
str1 = "days"
str2 = "10"
```

And I want to create a timedelta like:

```
timedelta(days=10)
```

But I could not manage to find on how to do it. I have seen some "dictionary unwrapping" on Stack Overflow, like `timedelta(**{str1=str2})` but it do not work.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I figure it out using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426003/using-expression-as-a-keyword-argument-for-string-template-identifiers-python) post. So If someone want to dynamically pass keywords to a function call it can use dict unpacking

```
(timedelta(**{str1: int(str2)}))
```